# C# selenium/phantomjs set global proxy

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, phantomjs

I need to setup phantomjs to use a proxy.  I have found many examples for java, javascript/node.js, etc.  But none for c# using selenium.  I need to set a global proxy and be able to change it without restarting the driver.  I believe it would be under driver.ExecutePhantomJS() but I also cant find what phantomjs script I would run to change the global proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the service:

```
OpenQA.Selnium.Proxy myproxy = new Proxy();
myproxy.httpProxy = ip +":"+port;
driverservice.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, myproxy);
```

After driver is running to change the proxy:

```
driver.ExecutePhantomJS("phantom.setProxy('"+ip+"', "+port+", 'http', '', '');")
```